# Regex for log fields not always in order

Tags: regex, logging, logstash, grok

I hope someone will be able to help me on that headache.
I am a bit stuck on a regex/grok/logstash syntax.
I am trying to parse kibana logs, but fields in logs not always comes in the same order.

Here are 3 logs as exemple.

```
{"name":"Kibana","hostname":"22e1923b59f3","pid":1,"level":30,"req":{"method":"POST","url":"/elasticsearch/_msearch?timeout=0&ignore_unavailable=true&preference=1438549037831","headers":{"host":"192.168.33.10:5601","connection":"keep-alive","content-length":"779","accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","origin":"http://192.168.33.10:5601","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36","content-type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","referer":"http://192.168.33.10:5601/","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6","cookie":"PHPSESSID=nhbu44n9jce33312je8346gm43; fastcoinlang=en; csrftoken=RAI1SVRsAGPmE490nhObxX9M1WYFuFjn"},"remoteAddress":"192.168.33.1","remotePort":56797},"res":{"statusCode":200,"responseTime":180,"contentLength":158203},"msg":"POST /_msearch?timeout=0&ignore_unavailable=true&preference=1438549037831 200 - 180ms","time":"2015-08-02T21:02:50.359Z","v":0}

{"name":"Kibana","hostname":"22e1923b59f3","pid":1,"level":30,"req":{"method":"GET","url":"/worker-json.js","headers":{"host":"192.168.33.10:5601","connection":"keep-alive","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36","accept":"*/*","referer":"http://192.168.33.10:5601/","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, sdch","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6","cookie":"PHPSESSID=nhbu44n9jce33312je8346gm43; fastcoinlang=en; csrftoken=RAI1SVRsAGPmE490nhObxX9M1WYFuFjn","if-none-match":"W/\"10ca1-14e40807fc0\"","if-modified-since":"Mon, 29 Jun 2015 18:07:20 GMT"},"remoteAddress":"192.168.33.1","remotePort":56797},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":1,"contentLength":0},"msg":"GET /worker-json.js 304 - 1ms","time":"2015-08-02T21:02:59.102Z","v":0}

{"name":"Kibana","hostname":"a274fbd7485b","pid":1,"level":30,"req":{"method":"GET","url":"/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0","headers":{"host":"192.168.33.10:5601","connection":"keep-alive","cache-control":"max-age=0","if-none-match":"W/\"ffac-14e40807bd8\"","if-modified-since":"Mon, 29 Jun 2015 18:07:19 GMT","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36","accept":"*/*","referer":"http://192.168.33.10:5601/","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, sdch","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6","cookie":"PHPSESSID=nhbu44n9jce33312je8346gm43; fastcoinlang=en; csrftoken=RAI1SVRsAGPmE490nhObxX9M1WYFuFjn"},"remoteAddress":"192.168.33.1","remotePort":59999},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":2,"contentLength":0},"msg":"GET /bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0 304 - 2ms","time":"2015-08-02T22:55:19.190Z","v":0}
```

What I could parse so far:

```
{\"name\":%{QS:name},\"hostname\":%{QS:hostname},\"pid\":%{INT:pid},\"level\":%{INT:level},\"req\":{\"method\":%{QS:req_method},\"url\":%{QS:req_url},\"headers\":{\"host\":%{QS:headers_host},\"connection\":%{QS:headers_connection}(,\"content-length\":%{QS:headers_content_length}|)(,\"accept\":%{QS:headers_accept}|)(,\"cache-control\":%{QS:headers_cache_control}|)(,\"if-none-match\":%{QS:headers_if_none_match}|)(,\"if-modified-since\":%{QS:headers_if_modified_since}|)(,\"origin\":%{QS:headers_origin}|)(,\"user-agent\":%{QS:headers_user_agent}|)(,\"accept\":%{QS:headers_accept}|)(,\"content-type\":%{QS:headers_content_type}|)(,\"referer\":%{QS:headers_referer}|)(,\"accept-encoding\":%{QS:headers_accept_encoding}|)(,\"accept-language\":%{QS:headers_accept_language}|)(,\"cookie\":%{QS:headers_cookie}|)},\"remoteAddress\":%{QS:remoteaddress},\"remotePort\":%{INT:remoteport}},\"res\":{\"statusCode\":%{INT:res_statuscode},\"responseTime\":%{INT:res_responsetime},\"contentLength\":%{INT:res_contentlength}},\"msg\":%{QS:res_msg},\"time\":\"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}\",\"v\":%{INT:v}}
```

With this I can take care if a field is missing, but not when one field comes before/after another one. How to capture without taking care of the field order?

If you have any tips on how to be more effective with the syntax I take it too!.

Comment: That looks like it's JSON, so you'd be best off parsing it with a JSON parser rather than using a regex.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was so much easier looking a JSON syntax (which did all the job) of the type:       

json{
        source => "message"
      }

Thanks a lot for your help. Good day!